# Uninstalling Flash Player manually, without the flash uninstaller

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, flash

We have flash player on our windows servers and I was assigned to uninstall them, but the catch here is that I can't use any external software therefore I can't download Flash Player Uninstaller provided by Adobe,

If anyone of you can help, I really appreciate that.

Comment: It ought to be listed in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features` and you ought to be able to uninstall it from there.

Comment: I should've mentioned that it is no where to be found in the programs and features, but it's installed and accessible.

Comment: Flash player is the part of "Desktop experience" function in Windows 2012. It seems we cannot uninstall it without loosing desktop features. Uninstallation will probably convert a server to headless mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed ***Deskop Experience*** from Windows Server 2012 R2 using:

*Server Manager -> Manage -> Remove Roles and Features -> Features - User Interfaces and Infrastructure ->* deselect *Desktop Experience*

Or uninstall it from Power Shell (don't forget "Run as Administrator"):

`Get-WindowsFeature Desktop-Experience | Uninstall-WindowsFeature`

Add `-Restart` to the end of the command above and server will restart automatically.

Server did not end up in headless mode, restart was is required.

On the other hand, two options *Graphical Management Tools* and *Infrastructure and Server Graphical Shell* next to *Desktop Experience* item will remove GUI and make server headless.

Adobe Flash Player in Internet Explorer is part of the Windows Experiece feature and Windows updates are available for it.
More details about [Adobe Flash Player in Internet Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/2755801).

*Windows Experience* contains:

Windows Media Player, Windows SideShow, Disk Cleanup, Sync Center, Sound Recorder, Character Map, Snipping Tool, Support for desktop apps, Windows Store etc.

More details about [Windows Experience](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn609826(v=ws.11).aspx).